# Can I use method for ordering in django?

Tags: python, django

Can I use method for ordering in django?

```
class Question(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True,
                               related_name='questions',
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    contents = models.TextField()

    def date_of_receive(self):
        try:
            return self.answers.first().creation.date()
        except AttributeError:
            return None
        except:
            assert False, 'error'

class Answer(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='answers')
    contents = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers', null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I want Question to order by 'date_of_receive'...

What should I do?

Comment: Just FYI, the bare "except" (the last clause of your try/except/except) doesn't do anything except mess up your traceback.  I recommend dropping it.  There's essentially never a reason to use an `except` clause without naming a specific exception -- in this case, your AttributeError exception does what you want and non-AttributeError exceptions should be allowed to "fall through" uncaught.

Answer (score 4):

You can order things in two ways: by using `order_by`, which relies on the database to sort for you, or by fetching all of the results into your application process' memory and sorting it there.  The database doesn't know anything about Python or your methods, so you can only order by the result of a method if you sort in memory.

In this case, however, your method can be reduced to a database call anyways.  `.order_by('answers__creation')` might give you what you want, but otherwise you can use aggregation and annotation to get only the FIRST creation datetime.  I think it looks something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Question.objects.annotate(date_of_receive=Min('answers__creation')).order_by('date_of_receive')
```

Note that there's no way to do this efficiently on a very large dataset.  If you have hundreds of thousands of rows then you should not sort in application memory at all, and sorting in database memory will take a long time.  At that point you'll need to denormalize your data.  However, only do that if you really think your dataset will get that big, because denormalizing data is a good way to introduce subtle bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Django's `order_by()` works on the the database level.

Although you can achieve ordering by doing something like

```
sorted(Question.objects.all(), key=lambda k: k.date_of_receive())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your result in python itself. Since *date_of_receive* is a method, you cannot sort it on the database level.